# Type of ID - image recognition

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

I have several images per user, for too many users for a human to go through.

One of the images, per user, is an ID.

I need to determine which image is the photo of an ID and I need to detect the type of ID (driving licence, passport, etc).

I'm looking for an API which can do the above (I'll send it the image files, it should tell me whether or not the image is an image of someone's ID; and what type if ID it is if yes).

Comment: If you're familiar to console applications you might use imagemagick. Can you provide more information ex. maximum price, os and what you've tried so far?